# Preventing an image width from resizing based on screen resolution

Tags: html, image, resolution

First of all, I'd like to mention there's no CSS/HTML related to this code, it goes straight to `<body>`

The image itself I'm placing over every bit of content on a page using z-index and pointer-effects:none, and what i've been attempting to achieve is causing the image to scale correctly with screen resolutions based on the height and still cover the screen aswell (it doesn't matter to me if some of it gets cut off), but no matter what I try the entirety of the image resizes itself to be smaller to fit

the code:

```
<div style="position:fixed;
float:left;
z-index:99999999;
bottom:0px;
left:0px;
pointer-events:none;">
<img src="http://www.millport.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Flower-festival.jpg"  width="100%" height="100%"></div>
<div id ="over"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZnraF/1/

Removing `width="100%"` only causes the entire image to go back to original size, and the popular `background-size: cover;` codes do nothing and only effect the background image itself.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLJBQ.png <-- I'm assuming it's possible to do this, does anyone have any suggestions? (note, the image i'm actually using for this is much wider and larger in general than the flower image.)

Answer (score 0):

if what you want to do is maintain the Image size the same no matter the resolution, try changing the image code like so:

```
<img 
src="http://www.millport.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Flower-festival.jpg"  style="width:100px; height:100px"/>
```

Just change the `px` value to the wanted pixels for width and height.